# Is it OK to add FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" in .NET 6 console app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc, .net-6.0, grpc-c#

I have a console app running on mac built on .NET 6. I need to use GRPC to communicate between another application using GRPC.

The `Grpc.Core` is not recommended and maintained anymore and I see the recommended option is to use  `Grpc.AspNetCore.Server`. In order to achieve this I need to add
`<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"/>` and `Grpc.AspNetCore`

Is this a good approach? By doing this am I converting my console app into a web app?

Is there any better way to implement this. Please let me know.

Comment: Do you want to expose GRPC endpoints from your application or call the endpoints exposed by another application?

Comment: Yes. I want to expose endpoint from my app and also want to call endpoints by the other app. But I want this to be limited only between these two apps. The second app is written in swift.

Currently using raw socket communication between these two. But facing lot of challenges with this approach

Comment: You can refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio). There it is explained how to create a GRPC service and how to create a GRPC client. The kind of packages you need to reference is different in the two cases.

Comment: The main point to take home is that if you want to create a GRPC client application, then you can do that from a plain old console application. If, instead, you want to create a server application you can't do that from a simple console application. You need to create a more complex application by using the proper project template in Visual Studio (refer to the documentation linked above for all the details)

Comment: You can safely mix a .NET client with a Swift server and vice versa. If you know the proto file which describes your server, you can use whatever GRPC client to call your server.

Comment: Regarding your question *am I converting my console app into a web app?*. If you want to create one or more gRPC services (which you have to), you need some sort of server to host the services. AspNetCore offers [these 4 server options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#server-options). The default server option is Kestrel, which is a cross-platform web server. So, depending on how you define a web app, yes you are kind of converting it into a web app. But you do not have to expose the server to the web.